# Liquibase generating changelog with invalid MySQL syntax, data type "JSON(1073741824)"

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I'm using liquibase version 3.8.8, with java-8 (java-8-openjdk-amd64) along with classpath pointing to mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar.

When I execute generateChangeLog on my existing MySQL 8.0.19 database specifying changelog.mysql.sql file, it successfully generates the changelog.

The changelog includes the following line

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (ID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, Name VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, Data JSON(1073741824) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_APP PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

which doesn't seems like a valid MySQL syntax, because the type `JSON(1073741824)` is not supported by MySQL, rather just `JSON` is supported.

Consequently doing `liquibase update` with generated changelog on another empty MySQL 8.0.19 database gives the error asking me to check the SQL syntax.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Removing 1073741824 from changelog works. Do you think there could be any issue using such a manually modified changelog file kept as version 1.0